# Spring Boot. How to modify the controller response before the serialization process

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, interceptor

I want to modify (intercept) the response object before the serialization process and after the controller returns the object.
I have a RestController and a User class like this:

```
public class User {
    public String name;
    public int id;
    public boolean hasErrors;
    public User(Sting name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.hasErrors = false;
    }
}

@RestController
public class UserController {
   @GetMapping("/")
   public User getUser() {
       return userService.performMagicAndGetUser();
   }
}
```

and I want to be able to modify the User object returned by the UserController::getUser method, just before it is serialized into the HttpServletResponse body as a JSON. So I want to modify the 'hasErrors' property based on what happened in the 'userService.performMagicAndGetUser' method and was stored in some request context holder. I want to modify the final response to the client for every request in every endpoint which is returning a User object.

Comment: You can also modify `new User("User Name", 1)` before return it !?

Comment: Can you explain your intention here? If it's just to modify `User`, why not do that in your controller (per @TinyOS). Is it that you want to add an HTTP header or an extra JSON element to each response? Please clarify.

Comment: Well you've said that you want to khnow if it's possible to modify the retuened user object of your rest endpoint before serialisation into HttpServletResonse! ok in that case why not you modify it in the getUser() method before the return clause ? `User u=new User("User Name", 1);` example : `u.setName("sample");` then your return it like `return u;`

Comment: @Dovmo yes, I need to modify the object in every response, but not inside the controller, I need to modify it maybe in a Request interceptor or something similar. The problem is that I do not know how to get the object as a POJO after the controller returns. Normally in a request interceptor, I will have the HttpServletResponse where the body is a byte stream or some kind of serialized data stream, and I need the POJO just before the serialization process and after the controller returns.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezSánchez I would edit your question/title to explain exactly the operation you'd like to perform on the object so that we can help you. Show more clearly what type of thing you're trying to modify in the response